# How to calculate the probability of many people tossing a fair coin many times will fall within specific range as a percentage?

Tags: probability

If 5 000 000 each people flip a fair coin 5000 times each. What is the percentage chance that every single person will get a result of 2000-3000 either heads or tails. In other words, no one can get 1800 heads and 3200 tails and vice versa.

Been working on this with a friend for a couple days and require a formula or reference to a program or site with sufficient accuracy or power please. The answer would also be helpful.

Layperson's terms or defined symbols please.

Also if you'd like to be credited with the answer on reddit please say so.

Comment: Look up "Binomial Distribution."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $p$ is the chance that a single person gets 2000-3000 of either heads or tails, then the answer is $p^{5000000}$. So it remains to compute focus on a single person and compute $p$.

---

The number of heads in 5000 flips is a $\text{Binomial}(5000, 1/2)$ random variable. If you use a computer to compute the probability by summing the probability of having 2000 heads, 2001 heads, 2002 heads, etc. up to 3000 heads, you will find that the probability is [incredibly close to $1$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BBinomial%5B5000%2Ck%5D+*+2%5E%28-5000%29%2C+k%2C+2000%2C+3000%5D).

Another way to see this is that the distribution of the number of heads in 5000 flips is very close to a normal distribution with mean $2500$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{5000 /4} \approx 35.36$. So having 2000-3000 heads is asking for the number of heads to be within $500 / \sqrt{5000/4} \approx 14$ standard deviations of the mean $2500$ which is extremely likely (99.7% of the mass of the normal distribution already lies within $3$ standard deviations of the mean).

---

Since you really want $p^{5000000}$, the precision of $p$ (how close $p$ is to $1$) will matter (since even $0.999^{5000000} \approx 0$). However, as you see in the WolframAlpha output above, $1-p \approx 10^{-45}$, so $$p^{5000000} = (1-(1-p))^{5000000} \approx 1 - 5000000 \cdot 10^{-45}$$
which is still incredibly close to $1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick and detailed response. I think it means it's likely. But don't understand a single one of those symbols. I'm guessing p is probability. I could look them up. Or if you'd be so kind and to clarify. In entire words only please.

Comment: also, does this demonstrate the chance that not a single person will get a result out of range? Trying.

Comment: so the probability is equal to um, times an exponent of 500000? See where I'm at.

Comment: okay got approximate, need precise

Comment: Thank you for your generosity, my friend and I can work on it. Would appreciate the clarity of you have the time please.

Comment: @dicedude The chance that a single person gets 2000-3000 heads is very very close to $100\%$ (see the Wolfram Alpha link for how close it is). It is slightly less likely for this to happen to every one of the 5000000 people, but the chance is also very close to $100\%$.

Comment: @dicedude My above approximation suggests the chance of it happening for all 5000000 people is over 99.99...9% (more than 30 nines after the decimal point).

Comment: Oh my gosh. Thank you so much!

Comment: You have solved an argument amount many people over 6 years. Here was the most recent: https://www.reddit.com/r/WorldofTanks/comments/jfvwpi/proof_wot_rigs_matches/